# Changing backgroundcolor of a view seems hard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, view

I want to change the background color of a view within the view controller. Selecting the view and opening the attributes inspector isn't showing that much. Should have an option here for the background.

[image]

Tried coding it within the `(void)viewDidLoad{}` with: `self.view.backgroundColor = [NSColor blueColor];` That isn't working either, no object of NSView.

What am I doing wrong? I read that the coding problem probably has something to with the newer version of Xcode. [coding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908836/adding-background-for-window-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already questioned and answered in 
[Best way to change the background color for an NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview)

Here the code for OS X

```
[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.view.layer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

wich xcode version are you using? This is how I change the backgroun color using the attributes inspector in Version 7.1 (7B91b)
[image]

Comment: Currently using 7.0.1. Writing for OS X, not for iOS.

Comment: The class is NSView. Is there a way this has something to do with the core graphics framework? I can't add a reference to the UIKit for example, so using UIColor won't work.

Comment: ah! ok, then it seems to be not so easy... may be this video can help you! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8eWIZ39W4A